# SPSS: How do I generate ID numbers from client ID variable that contains duplicate IDs in the order of the first date of each ID

Tags: duplicates, spss, longitudinal

Previously, I asked how to generate ID numbers from a client ID variable that contains duplicate IDs. I will use the same example data in this question but I would like to know how to generate ID numbers in the order of the first date of each ID. My client ID variable is string and has to remain as string.

My Data looks like:

```
ClientID TimeStamp

15137.45692 15/03/2021

10489.15789 03/02/2021

14143.96745 01/01/2021

15137.45692 15/01/2021

15137.45692 27/02/2021

14143.96745 08/03/2021
```

I would like it to look like:

```
ID ClientID TimeStamp

1 14143.96745 01/01/2021

1 14143.96745 08/03/2021
    
2 15137.45692 15/01/2021

2 15137.45692 27/02/2021

2 15137.45692 15/03/2021
    
3 10489.15789 03/02/2021
```

The previous code I tried was this:

```
sort cases by ClientID.
compute ID=1.
if $casenum>1 ID=lag(ID)+(ClientID<>lag(ClientID)).
exe.
```

However, whilst it gave me ID numbers for each ID, those ID numbers weren't ordered by TimeStamp.

Comment: Please add the code you tried and/or a link to your previous question, and explain what is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create the new ID the data needs to be sorted by ClientID. But then the new IDs will have the same order of the ClientID, while the order you want is not by the ClientID but by the first date of appearance. So first we need to calculate the first date for every ClientID, then we can use that to sort before creating the new ID.
Note: you need to make sure TimeStamp is defined as a date variable.

```
aggregate outfile=* mode=addvariables /break=ClientID /firstDate=min(TimeStamp).
sort cases by firstDate ClientID.
compute ID=1.
if $casenum>1 ID=lag(ID)+(ClientID<>lag(ClientID)).
exe.
```